# How to decode a gzip encoded JSON using Lotus-Script

Tags: json, httprequest, gzip, lotusscript

I get gzip encoded JSON content from a httprequest and I don't know how to decode it in Lotus Script.

```
Set webRequest = Session.createhttprequest()


    Call webRequest.Setheaderfield("cache-control", "no-cache")
    Call webRequest.Setheaderfield("Connection", "keep-alive")
    Call webRequest.Setheaderfield("Content-Type", "application/json")
    Call webRequest.Setheaderfield("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
    Call webRequest.Setheaderfield("Accept", "*/*")
    Call webRequest.Setheaderfield("Host", "graph.microsoft.com")
    Call webRequest.Setheaderfield("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate")

ret = webRequest.Get(Url)

ForAll b In ret
    responsJSON = responsJSON + Chr(b)
End ForAll

Set jsnav = session.CreateJSONNavigator(responsJSON)
```

I expect an JSON but get this error messag "Unable to Parse JSON string: Invalid value. Offset0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Domino/Notes are you on? Try 10.0.1 FP2 and use set webRequest.PreferJSONNavigator = true. This will retun the JSONNavigator directly and will skip some of the problems identified in https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10875724

Comment: Ok, it works, but just if I dont set this in the header `Call webRequest.Setheaderfield("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate")` seems litle bit wired for me. webRequest.PreferJSONNavigator = true this helps. And yes I am on 10.0.1 FP2. TY